# AddArc c# - Explain

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, graphicspath

I want to add arc to my draw using c# code. the syntax is:

```
AddArc(
    int x,
    int y,
    int width,
    int height,
    float startAngle,
    float sweepAngle)
```

Can someone describe me what are the width, the height start and sweep angle?

Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142518%28v=vs.110%29.aspx MSDN is your friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this kind of answers but..

From [`GraphicsPath.AddArc Method (Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Single, Single)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142518%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
width  
The width of the rectangular region that defines the ellipse from which the arc is drawn.

height
The height of the rectangular region that defines the ellipse from which the arc is drawn.

startAngle 
The starting angle of the arc, measured in degrees clockwise from the x-axis.

sweepAngle  
The angle between startAngle and the end of the arc.
```

Comment: I am sorry but the issue of start and sweep angle isn't clear foe me